# Nacos registry always drops

Tags: linux, docker, spring-cloud, nacos

Nacos in Linux server and other applications are made with docker deployment, but nacos always puzzling dropped, other deployed application won't drop, is this why?

Every time is to rerun nacos, very troublesome, have what good method can solve the problem of nacos always drops? Solving!!!!!!

Comment: An error because I am start other deployed in nacos registry service, visit, appeared the following error in the log：

Comment: The maximum number of tolerable server reconnection errors has been reached